# Dead Samsung Note 4

Tags: sync, restore, samsung-galaxy-note-4

I dropped my phone in the pool and now it won't turn on.  I took it to a repair place and was advised that it was to far gone.  I have about 3000 photos on the internal memory (stupid me didn't back up) and I didn't sync this phone to my samsung account.  My question is.. is there any possible way to sync my dead samsung note 4 to my samsung account through the computer???

Answer (score 0):

You're going to want to buy another same-model Note 4 off ebay and swap the logic boards around. It **has** to be same exact model, same carrier. You can check the label behind the battery for your model #. By swapping the logic boards, you can pinpoint where the problem is. If your phone works after that, then lucky you, it was just the USB board or screen causing the problem. This is your best shot at getting it running again. Yes, it will cost you some $$, but not as much as any of the ladder options.

If it doesn't work, at least you have a new phone to use. You can also just resell it on ebay. At this point you'll have to pay for a professional data recovery service, which requires sending your phone in to a professional to have your memory chip lifted off the board and probes hooked up to it to get the data off (risky). There is a similar service called JTAG that fixes phones that don't turn on, but IMO they usually don't recover data, they just reflash the phone to get it working. But if you know a guy, ask him what he can do.

Pray that one of those 2 options work for you. Good luck!